# Tour description - Later Day Saints?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

I was reading the tour, as I always do when I first visit a site, and I noticed the following error:

[image]

If this is indeed referring to the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, I request that the tour description be updated to reflect that.  Ideally, the full name of the Church should be used according to the official style guidelines:

> In the first reference, the full name of the Church is preferred: "The
>   Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints."

The rest of the guidelines can be found on this page: http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/style-guide.  I hope this post will aid future contributors to this site when discussing the Church and its beliefs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Later" was also misspelled. Thanks for pointing out the error! It has been fixed and is now the full name.